# Jest: TypeError: req.headers.get is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, jestjs

I i have this function that i use to find header in the request object:

```
export async function authorizeAccess(req: Request): Promise<Response | {}> {
    const access = req.headers.get('Access')
    if(!access) return Response.json('No access token provided',{status: 403, headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'}})
    
    const data = await signIn(access)
    if(!data) return Response.json('Invalid token', {status: 401})
    
    return data
}
```

This works perfectly fine outside the test, but when i try to make this test:

```
        test('Must return values correctly', async () => {
            const req = createRequest({
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    Access: testAccessKey
                }
            })
    
            const res = await authorizeAccess(req);
            
            expect(res).toHaveProperty('id')
        })
```

It throws error `TypeError: req.headers.get is not a function`

I thought that problem may be with old NodeJS (i used 16.x), but when updated to the 18.x (i referred to the compatibility list here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers/get) nothing changed. No help from googling.

My jest.config.mjs file:

```
import nextJest from 'next/jest.js'

const createJestConfig = nextJest({
  // Provide the path to your Next.js app to load next.config.js and .env files in your test environment
  dir: './',
})

// Add any custom config to be passed to Jest
/** @type {import('jest').Config} */
const config = {
  // Add more setup options before each test is run
  // setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],
 
  testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
}

// createJestConfig is exported this way to ensure that next/jest can load the Next.js config which is async
export default createJestConfig(config)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use Node.js environment, you can access the headers this way `const access = req.headers['access'];`